# Proving Bellman operator being a contraction

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces

I know that Bellman operator, defined as $T(f(x))=\sup_{y\in\Gamma(x)} {\phi(x,y)+\beta f(y)}$, is a contraction provided that $\beta\in(0,1)$ and $\phi$ is a bounded function on $Gr\Gamma$.

In order to prove this result I was trying to use Blackwell Theorem which states that an operator $T:B(X)\rightarrow B(X)$ is a $\beta$-contraction if $T$ is monotone and $T$ has the discounting property, i.e. $T(f+c)\leq T(f) +\beta c$, where $\beta\in (0,1)$.

How should I combine this two known results to prove that Bellman operator is a contraction? In particular, I do not understand how to use the fact that $\phi$ is bounded on $Gr\Gamma$.